# Select indices where x is nan while y is between two values

Tags: python, numpy

I've two arrays

```
x = np.array([1,np.nan,3,np.nan,5])
y = np.array([1,-2,3,4,15])
```

Now I would like to select the indices where `x = np.nan` only where `y` is between `0` and `10`. Separately like this:

```
np.where(isnan(x))
(array([1,3])
np.where(y>=0)
(array([0, 2, 3, 4])
np.where(y<10)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

But what to do to get:

```
(array[3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use parentheses (due to operator precendence) and the bitwise `&` operator for `AND`ing your conditions:

```
In [3]:

np.where(isnan(x) & (y >=0) & (y<10))
Out[3]:
(array([3], dtype=int64),)
```